# Replace only "(" and "," and "&" characters with space using Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm using this

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

This is replacing all special characters. I just want "( ) , &" characters to be replaced. using java

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("[()&,]+", ""); `

Comment: A non-word character: [^\w] , that's too much you need only to replace a few characters try @anubhava thing

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. It worked

Comment: You mentioned "space" in the title - you might want to add a space to the character class in @anubhava's suggested code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
s = s.replaceAll("[()&,]+", " ");
```

The first argument of the replaceAll function is a regular expression (regex) of what you wish to have replaced. Inside the square brackets are the characters to be replaced throughout the string. The + after the brackets means any of the characters inside those brackets, whether they appear once, or a dozen times, will be replaced with whatever the second argument is (in this case, it is just a space).

Comment: @konqi I understand why you say that, but it is not a good reason to delete this answer. anubhava chose to not post an answer, but only a comment. SO is about providing answers. If this answer answers the question, it should stay, regardless of who posted it.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra I certainly do not know whether anubhava chose not to post the comment as an answer or not. For all i know he/she could be sleeping. In any case this does not qualify as a good answer since it does not explain WHY this is the answer.

Comment: @konqi, I wasn't claiming that it is a good answer, merely pointing out that "some other user provided this same answer first, as a comment" is not a good reason to delete it. You are certainly correct that the answer could be much improved by providing some explanation of why it works.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Fine - I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm personally a big fan of regexes, a lot of devs are turned off by them. And in this case, you don't have to use a regex at all. If you have the Apache Commons Lang library already in your project (or feel like adding it) consider using the [replaceChars method of StringUtils class](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceChars(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) as follows:

```
s = StringUtils.replaceChars(s, "()&,", null);
```